# Deleting Duplicates in Dyadic Datasets (R)

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 309,888 observations and 121 variables. I would like to delete instances where the dyad is duplicated.

**Data**

```
 D1 <- data.frame(row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8),
           country = c("China", "China", "China", "China", "Myanmar", "Myanmar", "Myanmar", "Myanmar"),
           year = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991), 
           group_a = c("Tibetan", "Tibetan", "Han", "Tibetan", "Karens", "Bamar", "Bamar", "Bamar"), 
           group_b = c("Han", "Manchu", "Tibetan", "Han", "Bamar", "Shan", "Karens", "Karens"), 
           var1= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                   var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

**looks like**

```
  row country year group_a group_b var1 var2
1   1   China 1990 Tibetan     Han    0    0
2   2   China 1990 Tibetan  Manchu    0    0
3   3   China 1990     Han Tibetan    0    0
4   4   China 1991 Tibetan     Han    0    0
5   5 Myanmar 1990  Karens   Bamar    0    0
6   6 Myanmar 1990   Bamar    Shan    0    0
7   7 Myanmar 1990   Bamar  Karens    0    0
8   8 Myanmar 1991   Bamar  Karens    0    0
```

In this table, I would like to delete row 3 and row 7 as the combination of columns 'group_a' and 'group b' in row 3 are identical to row 1, same is the case for row 7 and row 5.

**Desired Output**

```
  row country year group_a group_b var1 var2
1   1   China 1990 Tibetan     Han    0    0
2   2   China 1990 Tibetan  Manchu    0    0
4   4   China 1991 Tibetan     Han    0    0
5   5 Myanmar 1990  Karens   Bamar    0    0
6   6 Myanmar 1990   Bamar    Shan    0    0
8   8 Myanmar 1991   Bamar  Karens    0    0
```

Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Comment: Pictures of data are not reproducible.  Please use the result from `dput()`

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I am not entirely sure if this is what you meant by i have included the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

D1[,c("group_a", "group_b")] = lapply(D1[,c("group_a", "group_b")], as.character)

D1 %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(tmp = paste(sort(c(group_a,group_b)), collapse = '')) %>%  
      group_by(country, year) %>% 
      distinct(tmp) %>% 
      select(-tmp)

#Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
#Groups: country, year

#  row country year group_a group_b var1 var2
#1   1   China 1990 Tibetan     Han    0    0
#2   2   China 1990 Tibetan  Manchu    0    0
#3   4   China 1991 Tibetan     Han    0    0
#4   5 Myanmar 1990  Karens   Bamar    0    0
#5   6 Myanmar 1990   Bamar    Shan    0    0
#6   8 Myanmar 1991   Bamar  Karens    0    0
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D1)[, c("group_a", "group_b") := lapply(.SD, as.character),
                             .SDcols = c('group_a', 'group_b')]

out = unique(D1[,tmp := paste(sort(c(group_a,group_b)), collapse = ''), 
                           by = row], by = c("tmp", "country", "year"))
out[,!"tmp", with = FALSE]

#   row country year group_a group_b var1 var2
#1:   1   China 1990 Tibetan     Han    0    0
#2:   2   China 1990 Tibetan  Manchu    0    0
#3:   4   China 1991 Tibetan     Han    0    0
#4:   5 Myanmar 1990  Karens   Bamar    0    0
#5:   6 Myanmar 1990   Bamar    Shan    0    0
#6:   8 Myanmar 1991   Bamar  Karens    0    0
```

base R alternative using *apply functions

```
D1[,c("group_a", "group_b")] = lapply(D1[,c("group_a", "group_b")], as.character)

D1$tmp = apply(D1[,c("group_a","group_b")], 1, 
         function(x) paste(sort(c(x[1], x[2])), collapse = ""))

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(D1, list(D1$country, D1$year)),
         function(x){ out = x[!duplicated(x$tmp),]; out[,-8]}))
```

Comment: Thank you, Veerendra. When I type in the code, however, I get the following error when running the first line: Error in apply(SOSdyad.country[, 4:46], 1, function(x) paste(sort(c(x[1],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: yes because you have mentioned wrong index inside country why did you write 4:46 ? And for your example data it works fine

Comment: oh, because in the actual dataset, the first group is on the 4th column and the second group is on the 46th column. should i have done it differently?

Comment: I still get the same error: Error in apply(SOSdyad.country[, c("groupname", "groupname_2")], 1, function(x) paste(sort(c(x[1],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: Worked great for me on the toy data. Also, if you want push that last line where `tmp` gets dropped into the piped chain, you could use this: `out = D1 %>% group_by(country, year) %>% distinct(tmp) %>% select(-tmp)`.

Comment: Now all the lines work but it doesn't change the dataset at all.

Comment: Unless you do not post the sample data similar to your original data you wont get what you are looking for in the answers. BTW the solution works perfectly fine for the dummy data you posted

Comment: I will find a way to post a sample of the original data and go from there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(D1)
setkey(D1,row)
D1[D1[, list(country,year,min(group_a,group_b),max(group_a,group_b)), by = row][, list(row = min(row)), by = c("country","year","V3","V4")][, row]]
```

For factors, you can either change the type back and forth (look at `as.character`), or adjust the call to:

```
D1[D1[, list(country,year,min(as.character(group_a),as.character(group_b)),max(as.character(group_a),as.character(group_b))), by = row][, list(row = min(row)), by = c("country","year","V3","V4")][, row]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for editing the question to make it clearer. I can't make the code seem to work, however. When I type in "setDT(D1, row)"; I get the following error: Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: row

Comment: @rbeginner in your example, you had a column called row. Is that not the case in your actual data set?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out, Chris. That line works perfectly now but when I type in the last line, I get this error: Error in Summary.factor(592L, 237L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  'min' not meaningful for factors

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out, Chris. After editing the call, I still get the following error: Error in `[.data.frame`(D1, , list(country, year, min(as.character(group_a),  : 
  unused argument (by = row)

Comment: @rbeginner - no problem. Did you run the `library(data.table)`, `setDT` and `setkey` lines as well?

Comment: yes, i did. i closed R and reran everything and now I am getting a different error: Error in min(as.character(group_a), as.character(group_b), ) : 
  argument 3 is empty

Comment: @rbeginner just get rid of that last comma and it should work. you can also recopy the lines above

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Now I don't get any errors but my dataframe doesn't change. I have exactly the same number of observations eventhough I know that every dyad is duplicated in the dataset.

Comment: @rbeginner it worked for the toy data set... D1 does stay the same, but the return of the last line should give you the data.table you want, which you can assign to a new variable using `<-`

Comment: Dear Chris, I have created a new dataset based on the code you gave me but it greatly reduced my data leaving me with only 7216 observation which isn't really possible since each group dyad has only one duplicate. Given that I had 309888 observations, the number of observations in the final dataset should be 154944. It seems like the command has deleted more dyads than necessary.

Comment: @rbeginner is the row column unique for every row? I can't see why the result would be any different unless the pattern of your data is inconsistent

Comment: yes, it is. i created a new row variable so that it would be unique.